# What is the proper antonym of featured?

Tags: meaning, grammar, antonyms

I am creating an application where the admin will have the ability to mark some items as featured or if the item is already featured he can switch back to unfeatured but by unfeatured I does not mean what dictionary says below but I mean normal. So what is the proper term for that?

> Definition of unfeatured. 1 obsolete : having ill-formed features : deformed. 2 : lacking features : unvaried. an unfeatured wilderness.

Image:
[image]

Comment: "ON" and "OFF" wouldn't work? Available vs Unavailable? Can't post an answer because I know nothing about programmes.

Comment: @Mari-LouA actually on and off will not express what the switch really mean, Its a tabular representation of all the items and at the end of each item there are a few actions  let me add an image of how it looks like.

Comment: You need to explain exactly what 'featured', in the way you are using it, means. 'Having distinctive features' or 'included'? Your text seems to indicate the latter.

Comment: Since the question and it's potential answers range outside English per se, I would suggest taking this question to https://ux.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Featured, Not Featured.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using 'highlighted' instead of 'featured' and 'unhighlighted' as the antonym.

Comment: That sounds good.